Why does mean prediction go flat after more data points are added in Gaussian Process Regressor
Im trying to do a Bayesian optimization in a robot simulator to find optimal Kd and Kp values that fit a desired trajectory (Sinusoidal motion). First I make some random movements of the arm using random Kp and Kd values within a given range and track the error from the desired motion. In the Gaussian Process I noticed that after about 29 calls the mean prediction looks good but then at 30 calls the prediction goes flat (second image). Why is that, is there too many data points to make a fit?
btw im using a Matern kernel here but the same happens for RBF


rbf_kernel = Matern(
length_scale=1.0,            # Initial length scale
length_scale_bounds=(1e-2, 1e2)  # Bounds for length scale
)

# Create and fit the GP regressor
gpkd0 = GaussianProcessRegressor(
    kernel=rbf_kernel,
    normalize_y=True,
    random_state=42
)
gpkd0.fit(np.array(kd0_values).reshape(-1,1), tracking_errors)
kd0_range = np.linspace(0.0, 100, 200).reshape(-1, 1)

y_mean_kd0, y_std_kd0 = gpkd0.predict(kd0_range, return_std=True)

print("y_mean_kd0: ", y_mean_kd0)
print("y_std_kd0: ", y_std_kd0)

plt.plot(kd0_range, y_mean_kd0, 'k-', lw=1.5, zorder=9, label='Mean prediction')
plt.fill_between(kd0_range.ravel(), y_mean_kd0 - 1.96 * y_std_kd0, y_mean_kd0 + 1.96 * y_std_kd0,
                alpha=0.5, fc='orange', ec='None', label='95% confidence interval')
plt.scatter(kd0_values, tracking_errors, c='blue', s=50, zorder=10, edgecolors=(0, 0, 0), label='Observations')
plt.title("Gaussian process regression on noise-free dataset Kd")
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('f(X)')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.close()


It would be easier to help if you could provide some code. Do you do any hyperparameter optimization? And how long is the length scale in your kernel? It looks quite short.
Also, are all the observables always going to be around 8000 - 9000? Then you might want to reduct them, say by a factor of 100, to decrease the differences between you target values. You could always reapply some scaling.

A suggestion is to multiply your kernel with ConstantKernel with some bounds in order to allow for amplitude scaling of your kernel. Also, you could add n_restarts_optimizer=10 or some other number to your gpkd0 to allow for several hyperparameter optimization attempts.

Sorry, yea your right I should add code ill update that now. Basically the 8000-9000 range is the tracking error and the X axis is the Kd input. To calculate the tracking error I do this:
tracking_error = np.sum((measured_angles - desired_angles)**2)
